# Scala - How to check which regex pattern match a string

Tags: scala

Assume I have more than 30 regex patterns:

```
val pattern1 = """(pat)(tern)(1)""".r
val pattern2 = """(pat)(tern)(1)""".r
val pattern3 = """(pat)(tern)(1)""".r
...
```

I want to check which pattern matches a string. Something like this

```
val s = "MyString"

s match {
 case pattern1 => grup 1 of pattern1
 case pattern2 => grup 2 of pattern2
 case pattern3 => grup 3 of pattern3
 ...
 case _ => "No pattern match"
}
```

Comment: An array of patterns walked through is as (in)efficient - no efficient way unless making one large pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In your case,you can do something like this:

```
val s = "MyString"

s match {
   case k if s.matches(pattern1.regex) => //.....do something
   case k if s.matches(pattern2.regex) => //.....do something
   case k if s.matches(pattern3.regex) => //.....do something
   ...
   case _ => "No pattern match"
```

}